# Append form submitted values as url parameters

Tags: jquery

Im trying to append the form submitted values as url parameters url encoded to the thank you page. How can i do that?

```
$('#bootstrapForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var extraData = {}
    $('#bootstrapForm').ajaxSubmit({
        data: extraData,
        dataType: 'jsonp',  // This won't really work. It's just to use a GET instead of a POST to allow cookies from different domain.
        error: function () {
            // Submit of form should be successful but JSONP callback will fail because Google Forms
            // does not support it, so this is handled as a failure.

            // You can also redirect the user to a custom thank-you page:
             window.location = 'http://www.rositarococo.com/gracias.html'
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: try this `data: JSON.stringify(extraData),` make sure your variable/object match parameters method in your server side.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need would be a way to convert the `extraData` object into a URL-parameter string? One way of doing that could be:

```
var queryString = Object.keys(extraData).map(key => key + '=' + params[key]).join('&');
```

Alternatively you can also access the input fields in your form directly by using jquery's `serialize()` method:

```
var querString = $("form").serialize()
```

(You might have to make the selector a bit more specific if there are more than one forms on our page.)

In both case you just append it to your URL:

```
window.location = 'http://www.rositarococo.com/gracias.html?'+queryString
```